# Is there a way to convert any English word to Japanese Kana？

Tags: kana

Recently, I've been dealing with Japanese grapheme-to-phonneme conversion. But sometimes, there are plain English words in the text. So I wonder is there a way to convert these English words into Japanese Kana？

e.g.

```
gravity -＞ グラビティ
```

I'm thinking about looking up the English word in a pronouncing dictionary and then using some rules that map a specific pronunciation pattern to Kana.

Comment: Japanese as any language does it (that is, they use foreign words, strongly adapted). The language has CV syllables and its writing is adapted to it. That makes it difficult to transliterate words like "pearl"  or "Arnold". How much accuracy do you expect?